# Javascript date returning NAN in IE8

Tags: javascript, date, nan

I am trying to parse date like this `2012-12-07T16:18:15+05:30` which I am receiving from database in string format.
The parse function I am using is:

```
var jstime = new Date("2012-12-07T16:18:15+05:30"); 
 var h = jstime.getHours();
var m = jstime.getMinutes();
var s = jstime.getSeconds();
var f = "am"
if(h >= 12)
{
    f = "pm";
    h = h - 12;
}
if(h == 0)
{
    h = 12;
}
var str;
str = jstime.toDateString();
str = str +"," + h.toString() + ":" + m.toString() + ":" + s.toString() + " " + f.toString();
```

However,**IE8 browser returning NAN** at very first line i.e. jstime is NAN in IE8,while working fine in other browsers.

so, Is there any alternate way to parse date that works well in all browsers?

 I need it accepts date in above format & returns date in format: 
`Fri Dec 07 2012,4:18:15 pm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can be sure of the format, you can regex it:

```
var match = "2012-12-07T16:18:15+05:30".match(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)([+-])(\d\d):(\d\d)/);
var jstime = new Date();
jstime.setUTCFullYear(parseInt(match[1],10));
jstime.setUTCMonth(parseInt(match[2],10)-1);
jstime.setUTCDate(parseInt(match[3],10));
jstime.setUTCHours(parseInt(match[4],10)-parseInt(match[7]+"1",10)*parseInt(match[8],10));
jstime.setUTCMinutes(parseInt(match[5],10)-parseInt(match[7]+"1",10)*parseInt(match[9],10));
jstime.setUTCSeconds(parseInt(match[6],10));
```

But if it's coming from the server-side, you may be able to format it more reliably there.

Comment: Hello, this works but I just want to ask have you tested on other dates so that I canuse it directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this -

```
date = Date.parse("2012-12-07T16:18:15+05:30");
var jstime = new Date(date); 
var h = jstime.getHours();
var m = jstime.getMinutes();
var s = jstime.getSeconds();
continue your code .....
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Both date and jstime are NAN in IE8